# How do I set up Java "extension methods"?

Tags: java, extension-methods

I see that Java 8 should support code like this:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Dave");
List<String> filteredNames = names
    .filter(e -> e.length() >= 4)
    .into(new ArrayList<String>());

for (String name : filteredNames) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

But when I fire up IntelliJ and try to put these in, the `filter` and `into` functions don't exist. I can get lambdas working fine, but the "extension methods", don't appear. Is there something that has to be set up first?

Comment: Didn't the APIs change? (Trying to look for API docs or browseable source on openjdk, but failing.) Edit: Yes `names.stream()` then you can `filter` and `collect`.

Comment: names.stream() isn't defined? I guess I'm missing something simple and crucial.